# VBA Public Function "Compile Error: Expected: List separator or )"

Tags: excel, vba, function, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm writing my first function and I'm creating a function for a weighted average formula.

This works fine when I use it as a sub and define the values, but I'm getting this error when testing the function in the immediate window.

> Compile error:
>
> Expected: list separator or )
>
> [image: Compile error: Expected: list separator or )]

I've tried playing around with the data types to no avail.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Public Function WeightedAverage(data() As Range, values() As Range, TotalValue As Range) As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Sum As Variant
    For i = 1 To UBound(data)
        Sum = Sum + values(i, 1) / TotalValue * data(i, 1)
    Next i
    WA = Sum / UBound(data)
End Function
```

Test:

```
?WeightedAverage(WIP_2!R12:R15,WIP_2!S12:S15,"150")
```

[image]

Comment: Just throw it in a cell and use it that way, much easier.  If you do it via code, you need to use VBA notation for specifying a range.  Not to mention that your last parameter is specified as a range and you're passing in "150".  You need to check that.  The parameters aren't quite right in general, there's a bit to change here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Weighted Average UDF

- Whatever you're doing here, according to this [link](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/weighted-average.html), that's not how you calculate the weighted average (the last parameter seems redundant, dividing in the loop is wrong).
- The suggested `SUMPRODUCT/SUM` formula solution in the provided link will fail if there are cells not containing numeric values while the following function will ignore (skip) those cells.

**Weighted Average**

```
Option Explicit

Function WeightedAverage( _
    ByVal ScoreColumnRange As Range, _
    ByVal WeightColumnRange As Range) _
As Double
    
    ' Compare the number of rows and use the smaller number.
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = ScoreColumnRange.Rows.Count
    Dim wrCount As Long: wrCount = WeightColumnRange.Rows.Count
    If wrCount < rCount Then rCount = wrCount
    
    ' Create the references to the column ranges.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ScoreColumnRange.Cells(1).Resize(rCount)
    Dim wrg As Range: Set wrg = WeightColumnRange.Cells(1).Resize(rCount)
    
    ' Write the values from the column ranges to arrays.
    Dim sData As Variant, wData As Variant
    If rCount = 1 Then
        ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = srg.Value
        ReDim wData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): wData(1, 1) = wrg.Value
    Else
        sData = srg.Value
        wData = wrg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Declare additional variables to be used in the For...Next loop.
    Dim sVal As Variant, wVal As Variant ' Current Values
    Dim r As Long ' Rows Counter
    Dim tWeight As Double ' Total Weight
    Dim tProduct As Double ' Total Sum
    
    ' Calculate the total weights and the total products.
    For r = 1 To UBound(sData, 1)
        sVal = sData(r, 1)
        If IsNumeric(sVal) Then ' prevent invalid score
            wVal = wData(r, 1)
            If IsNumeric(wVal) Then ' prevent invalid weight
                tWeight = tWeight + wVal
                tProduct = tProduct + sVal * wVal
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    If tWeight = 0 Then Exit Function ' all were invalid
    
    ' Calculate and return the weighted average (the result).
    WeightedAverage = tProduct / tWeight ' maybe you want to round?

End Function
```

**Your Code Revised**

```
Function WeightedAverage( _
    ByVal DataColumnRange As Range, _
    ByVal ValuesColumnRange As Range, _
    ByVal TotalValue As Double) _
As Double
    
    ' Compare the number of rows and use the smaller number.
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = DataColumnRange.Rows.Count
    Dim vrCount As Long: vrCount = ValuesColumnRange.Rows.Count
    If vrCount < rCount Then rCount = vrCount
    
    ' Create the references to the column ranges.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = DataColumnRange.Cells(1).Resize(rCount)
    Dim vrg As Range: Set vrg = ValuesColumnRange.Cells(1).Resize(rCount)
    
    ' Write the values of the column ranges to arrays.
    Dim dData As Variant, vData As Variant
    If rCount = 1 Then
        ReDim dData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): dData(1, 1) = drg.Value
        ReDim vData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): vData(1, 1) = vrg.Value
    Else
        dData = drg.Value
        vData = vrg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Declare additional variables to be used in the For...Next loop.
    Dim dVal As Variant, vVal As Variant ' Current Values
    Dim r As Long ' Rows Counter
    Dim tCount As Long ' Total Count
    Dim Total As Double ' Total Value
    
    ' Calculate the Total? (there should be a math term for it)
    For r = 1 To UBound(dData, 1)
        dVal = dData(r, 1)
        If IsNumeric(dVal) Then ' prevent invalid data
            vVal = vData(r, 1)
            If IsNumeric(vVal) Then ' prevent invalid value
                tCount = tCount + 1
                Total = Total + dVal * vVal / TotalValue
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    If tCount = 0 Then Exit Function ' all were invalid
    
    ' Calculate and return the weighted average (the result).
    WeightedAverage = Total / tCount ' maybe you want to round?

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. That's great. Sorry I'm new to VBA code so didn't add much to it. My issue with calculating the weighted average is that I didn't have a weights column in my raw data and it is quite manual to have to create, therefore I wanted a function to deal with calculating the weights and applying it to whatever value I need.

Comment: - Just wanted to add that what you've written there works perfectly for what I want - Cheers mate

Comment: Sorry last comment ... This really helped as I didn't even think to account for non-numeric values and properly defining the array - particularly as I'm picking up entire columns with headers etc. I got rid of the "/ tcount" at the end though as didn't need it. Reconciled with a manual count and it works a charm - cheers

Comment: Sorry for not understanding the concept of weighted average. It is clearer now (you're using the second function without the last division). It is refreshing when someone takes a special interest in the writing. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

As @Skin mentioned you can revise your code a little bit. I removed the brackets in your parameter section. Further you should call the function within a cell and assign each parameter to a cell/a range of cells.

The variable "WA" is not defined anywhere in your code. That causes maybe your error. To get a return value from a user defined function (UDF) you should assign the variable "sum" to the functions name.

If my feedback is a valid answer to your question, please mark it as an answer. Thanks!

```
Public Function WeightedAverage( _
    data As Range, _
    values As Range, _
    TotalValue As Range _
        ) As Double

    Dim i As Integer
    
'You need containers for your parameters, which can be more then one cell

    Dim arrData As Variant: arrData = data
    Dim arrValues As Variant: arrValues = values
    
    Dim Sum As Double
    
'Both arrays need the same size, optional, I thought that might help a little bit
    
    If UBound(arrData, 1) <> UBound(arrValues) Then Exit Function

    For i = 1 To UBound(arrData, 1)

    Sum = Sum + arrValues(i, 1) / TotalValue * arrData(i, 1)

    Next i

'Assign the variable "sum" to the functions name

    WeightedAverage = Sum / UBound(arrData, 1)

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Sergeij! Yep the issue was I didn't create those containers. I'm new to VBA (as you can probably tell...).